# creating horizontal interactive report to display week wise data

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-18.2

I am creating a report to display Weekwise day wise meals as show below table

```
Week 1                  
Sunday   Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Monday   Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Tuesday  Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
WednesdayMeal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Thursday Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Friday   Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Saturday Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5

Week 2                  
Sunday   Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Monday   Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Tuesday  Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
WednesdayMeal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Thursday Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Friday   Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
Saturday Meal 1 Meal 2  Meal 3  Meal 4  Meal 5
```

I want No of Weeks Like 2 Weeks and there are 7 days and in easch there are 3 4 5 or 6 or any number of meals in a day 
i want to display days vertically week wise in a Interactive Report or Classic Report.Also for more graphical display please see below link

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_8WtTgYjgC8ySiNZWNgzouIlUE6zgj2L

Comment: You can try Pivot option in the Interactive Report

Comment: Ok but pivot will show like Image as i shown in column

Comment: Max Meals are 6

Comment: Why you are using Interactive Report? You can try List Card Template

Comment: How card will be Grouped by Week and Week Day to Show Meals of a day

Comment: Can u help me out i context of some example

Comment: Unfortunately if you use images to display your requirements you immediately reduce the number of people who can help, as many of us do not have access to dump sites (because of firewall restrictions).

Comment: @Ahamed Please see my answer as this was what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this Using `htp.p` Simply Using Media Query in CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.body{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.menu{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding:0px;
}
.menu li{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:  0vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 1px auto;
}
.menu li i{
  font-size:24px;
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius:50%;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  cursor:pointer;
} 
.div {

border: 1px solid #1C6EA4;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1250px) {

    .menu li {

    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;


}

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3 class="list-heading">Week</h3>
<div class="div">
<h3 class="list-heading">Day</h3>
<div class="div">
<ul class="menu">

    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>6</span></li><br>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>6</span></li><br>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>6</span></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i><span>6</span></li>

</ul>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```